# What's the recommended approach for allocating an object in an instance methode, which will later on be returned?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

For example look at the following example:

Code1

```
-(NSString*)getString{
    return [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"test"] autorelease];
}

-(void)printTestString{
    NSString *testStr = self.getString;
    [testStr retain]
    NSLog(@"%@",testStr);
    [testStr release]
}
```

Code2

```
-(NSString*)getString{
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"test"];
}

-(void)printTestString{
    NSString *testStr = self.getString;
    NSLog(@"%@",testStr);
[testStr release];
}
```

Code 1 and Code 2 should be valid Code Snippets and no leaks should appear.

Code 1 uses autorelease so the return variable has to be retained in printTestString and after using it released. So there is a small Overhead here because of autorelease.

Code 2 doesn't release the NSString in getString so you have to  only release it after using it. Seems your have to write less and you dont have overhead because no autorelease is used.

Which one is the de facto "standard" approach that is used out there?

Another thing I was asking myself. Could the autorelease in getString and the retain with

```
[testStr retain]
```

be a problem, when the autorelease pool releases the variable right after

```
NSString *testStr = self.getString;
```

then the string would be gone. Is that possible or does the compiler prevent that sort of thing?

Thanks

-Sebo

Comment: @MusiGenesis Here's my recommended approach: if you don't like Obj-C, don't program in it and don't answer people's Obj-C questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
-(NSString*)getString{
    return [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"test"] autorelease];
}

-(void)printTestString{
    NSString *testStr = self.getString;
    NSLog(@"%@",testStr);
}
```

Your getString method autoreleases the NSString, which means printTestString doesn't need to retain or release it. Autoreleasing in getString makes sense, because it alloced the object and is therefore the 'owner' of the object. I suggest studying Objective-C's memory management rules before proceeding, as they are very important.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH

Comment: ok, but I still have to use autorelease. I hoped I could solve it by not using it. Seems like I have to. I really like it, when my code is as efficient as possibile.

Comment: you don't have to, but when you have a method that creates and returns an object, you should. everyone likes it when their code is efficient as possible. calling autorelease just adds it to an already existing pool you didn't create (unless you did). when that pool drains, your object receives a release message. that's the only overhead, it really isn't that big of a deal.

Comment: Ok JakeVA, Thank you. I'm convinced and stick with autorelease.

Comment: @sebo Glad to hear it. Could you mark this as the answer to your question?

Answer (score 2):

Jake's answer is correct for almost all of the situations you'll need to return an object from a method, but there are cases where you might want to return something that isn't autoreleased.  From the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH) (Mac version, but they're the same rules):

> You take ownership of an object if you
>   create it using a method whose name
>   begins with “alloc” or “new” or
>   contains “copy” (for example, alloc,
>   newObject, or mutableCopy), or if you
>   send it a retain message.

Also, from the [Coding Guidelines for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/FrameworkImpl.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001286-BAJIBFHD):

> In your methods and functions that
>   return object values, make sure that
>   you return these values autoreleased
>   unless they are object-creation or
>   object-copy methods (new, alloc, copy
>   and their variants). “Autoreleased” in
>   this context does not necessarily mean
>   the object has to be explicitly
>   autoreleased—that is, sending
>   autorelease to the object just before
>   returning it. In a general sense, it
>   simply means the return value is not
>   freed by the caller.
>
> For performance reasons, it’s
>   advisable to avoid autoreleasing
>   objects in method implementations
>   whenever you can, especially with code
>   that might be executed frequently
>   within a short period; an example of
>   such code would be a loop with unknown
>   and potentially high loop count.

Therefore, methods containing the prefix `alloc` or `new`, or those that contain the word `copy` by convention will have you returning objects that are not autoreleased.  In fact, the Clang Static Analyzer understands this convention and will assume non-autoreleased objects being returned from methods that follow these naming rules.

I've used the `new` prefix in situations where I preferred not to return autoreleased objects (tight loops where I didn't want to manage an autorelease pool, etc.).  Again, returning autoreleased objects is what's recommended in almost all cases, but there are some times where you might want to avoid that.